# Generating PropTypes for React Components written in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

We're creating a library of components for our internal applications. The old version of that library was written in `JavaScript` and `JSX`, thus we have declared `propTypes` for all the components for type-safety.
The newer version of the component library is written in `TypeScript`. For type-safety we used interfaces for `PropTypes` such as the following -

```
interface Props {
    size?: 'small' | 'large';
    color?: string;
    text?: string;
}
export class MyComponent extends React.Component<Props, any> { ... }
```

This was working fine since the newer projects using those components were written in TypeScript too (We do publish `d.ts` file for all the component classes). Now we needed to update the component library in the old projects too. Since they were not using TypeScript, the type-safety were not working. They're still relying on the old propTypes way for type-safety.

```
//Usage of MyComponent
<MyComponent size={20} color={'red'} text={'HelloWorld'} />
//Size must be one of 'small' or 'large' not the numeric value.
```

So my question is, what are the ways of handling this issue of using TypeScript (and tsx) written components in a non-TypeScript project?

There're some ways I've identified -

- Using some parser for d.ts file
- Creating a HoC for all the components
- Writing propTypes along with interfaces for all the components manually.

Are there any other cleaner and less manual way?

Comment: Could you share some of the legacy code? Otherwise this question is just too vague to answer. I believe you could extract the interface form propTypes but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I've added an example which is for a UI component I have created. It's an actual use-case and I am still not sure how can I enforce the prop type-safety here. I have many use cases for many other components since it's a UI Component library and the legacy projects are too complex to be updated to use TypeScript.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A perfect question! I'm looking into this exact problem myself right now.

First of all, I can agree that TypeScript is not a 100% replacement for PropTypes, because:

1. If you are building a library and it's being consumed by a project in vanilla JavaScript, the typings could not help to detect all the problems.
2. PropTypes are working dynamically at runtime, while TypeScript checks are only run statically.
3. PropTypes could be used to get information about a component at runtime, while type definitions are lost at runtime.

My search showed me the following possibilities:

- [babel-plugin-typescript-to-proptypes](https://github.com/milesj/babel-plugin-typescript-to-proptypes)

It allows to actually generate PropTypes during TypeScript compilation. It works as a plugin for Babel. The drawback is that you have to use Babel in order to utilize this functionality. Actually, I've posted a question: [Using the plugin without Babel?](https://github.com/milesj/babel-plugin-typescript-to-proptypes/issues/9), but I have my doubts that it could be possible.

- [prop-types-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/prop-types-ts)

As I can see from the documentation, this is not a fully compatible PropTypes generator, but instead a replacement, which uses it's own implementation for type checking at runtime. I would prefer my PropTypes to be fully compatible with the official implementation though.

---

You have to choose what are acceptable for you and what is your project's requirements are. If you are fine with using Babel I would recommend the first choice. However, if you only need to make sure that type checking is working at runtime, than second approach could be viable.

As for me, I think I will have to keep both TypeScript typings and manual PropTypes in sync for now, because I'm not using Babel and I don't really like a custom PropTypes implementation.

Maybe, one sunny day, we will find some resources to actually write our own PropTypes generator in our company and will share it with everyone.

---

Here's a typing trick that could be used to keep PropTypes in sync with typings:

```
import * as PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';


export interface IconProps {
  name: string;
}

export class Icon extends PureComponent<IconProps> {

  static propTypes: { [key in keyof IconProps]: any } = {
    name: PropTypes.string
  };

  render() {
    return <i className="dc-icon">{this.props.name}</i>;
  }

}
```

This will force `propTypes` object to has exactly the same properties that your props interface.

Comment: So, we have to use work arounds. I thought there're some support from TypeScript for this and I missed that.

Comment: Yep, it looks like TypeScript guys doesn't see this as a viable use case. It looks like they think that TypeScript typings are a replacement for PropTypes. Even the discussion issue is locked on this subject, which is sad.